# Is it possible to scroll popup menu vertically?

Tags: c++, winapi, drop-down-menu

A popup menu in a window for my Win32 application may contain a large list of items:

[image]

I'm visually setting the currently selected menu item by using [`CheckMenuRadioItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647621%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) as such:

```
::CheckMenuRadioItem(m_hMainMenu, 
    nRange_FirstId, nRange_LastId, nSelectedItemId, MF_BYCOMMAND);
```

The issue is that if the item selected is outside the screen boundaries, its (radio) check is not visible. So I was wondering, since there is a way to manually scroll the menu using those up- and down- arrows (highlighted above), is there a way for me to scroll it vertically using an API, kinda what [`EnsureVisible`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tbtcxzsf.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) does for the ListCtrl?

Comment: Even if there were an API to scroll the menu, I'm not aware of an API that returns the visible range of items. So even if you solve that issue, you still only have half a solution.

Comment: @IInspectable: Oh, yeah, you're right :(

Comment: Maybe UI Automation can (directly or indirectly) query for visibility of menu items.

Comment: @IInspectable: Either that or just use a combination of `SM_CYMENU`, `SM_CYMENUCHECK` and `SM_CYMENUSIZE` from `GetSystemMetrics`. But visibility is not that much of an issue here, as I don't need to know it "for sure." For instance, I can "overscroll" it "aiming" for the middle of the screen. The issue is how to implement automated scrolling itself? So far all I can think of is simulating mouse clicks on those up-and-down arrows, which would be a kludgy colusion as that menu scrolls very slowly & one needs to hold that button for a while before it gets anywhere.

Comment: Scrolling can be done using UI Automation.

Comment: @IInspectable: Awesome! Do you know any specifics? I'm not that well versed in UI automation.

Comment: The easiest way is to use the [Inspect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318521.aspx) tool. That'll show you all sorts of information, automation IDs, the accessible tree. That should bet you started to find your way around the application as seen by UI Automation.

Comment: @IInspectable: Thanks for your help.

Comment: I would say that a system with so many items on a popup menu that it will take the entire vertical screen space is a poor design and something else should be considered (perhaps a combo-box on a toolbar as an alternative).

Comment: Questions like this always remind me to the dreaded Win9x start menu, which luckily got replaced by something like a treeview in Vista. How often users need to switch countries? Does it really need to be a popup menu, or would a dialog with a combo-box suffice? Then, for users who switch often, put only the most-recently used countries in a popup menu with limited number of items.

Comment: Wow, what would I do without your valuable contribution?